# AVPlayer pause live stream on iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming, avplayeritem

Im having difficulties trying to resume live stream playback from previously paused moment.

On iOS 9.2 and below player continued to play from paused moment.
On iOS 9.3 and above, when i resume playing, i receive "playerBufferEmpty" and AVPlayerItemTimeJumpedNotification, and as a result playback doesnt continue from the paused moment.

This looks like an issue in AVPlayer since everything works on iOS versions 9.2 and below. I also tried playerItem.canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamingWhilePaused , but it doesnt help.

Are there any changes in AVPlayer/AVPlayerItem regarding this from iOS 9.2 to iOS 9.3?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. I have a similar problem, but do not receive `playerBufferEmpty` any more! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36858988/avplayer-does-not-fire-playbackbufferempty-but-does-not-play-either